# Error: (SystemJS) exports is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an .net core mvc + angular application. The mvc framework handles the user management and when the user lands on particular areas of the application, angular takes over.
So when I added one angular-2 (stats) app to the site and it was working. I needed to implement another functionality so I added another angular-2 app (practices) to the same solution. Everything was fine. Angular-4 came up. So changed the references to angular-4 and since I was working on the 2nd angular app did not check on the 1st angular app for a while. Now when I try to run the 1st angular app (stats) I get this error while the 2nd app loads angular.

Both apps share the systemjs.config.js, package.json, tsconfig.json, typings.json.

The error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) exports is not defined
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at eval (http://localhost:60660/apps/common/date.extentions.js:2:23)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval (http://localhost:60660/apps/common/daterange.component.js:13:1)
    at eval (http://localhost:60660/apps/common/daterange.component.js:40:4)
    at eval (http://localhost:60660/apps/common/daterange.component.js:41:3)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
Evaluating http://localhost:60660/apps/common/date.extentions.js
Evaluating http://localhost:60660/apps/common/daterange.component.js
Evaluating http://localhost:60660/apps/stats/app.module.js
Evaluating http://localhost:60660/apps/stats/main.js
Error loading http://localhost:60660/apps/stats/main.js
    at eval (http://localhost:60660/apps/common/date.extentions.js:2:23)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval (http://localhost:60660/apps/common/daterange.component.js:13:1)
    at eval (http://localhost:60660/apps/common/daterange.component.js:40:4)
    at eval (http://localhost:60660/apps/common/daterange.component.js:41:3)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
Evaluating http://localhost:60660/apps/common/date.extentions.js
Evaluating http://localhost:60660/apps/common/daterange.component.js
Evaluating http://localhost:60660/apps/stats/app.module.js
Evaluating http://localhost:60660/apps/stats/main.js
Error loading http://localhost:60660/apps/stats/main.js
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            stats: 'apps/stats/',
            practices: 'apps/practices',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            stats: {
                main: 'main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            practices: {
                main: 'main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: 'index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.13",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.3.0",
    "spinkit": "1.2.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "concurrently": "3.1.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-environments": "0.1.1",
    "gulp-rimraf": "0.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "2.2.2",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "typings": "~2.1.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },

    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "wwwroot/lib",
      "typings"
    ]

  }
```

typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#7.0.0+20170110233017"
  }
}
```

date.extensions.ts

```
export { }

// DATE EXTENSIONS
// ================

declare global {
    interface Date {
        addDays(days: number, useThis?: boolean): Date;
        isToday(): boolean;
        clone(): Date;
        isAnotherMonth(date: Date): boolean;
        isWeekend(): boolean;
        isSameDate(date: Date): boolean;
        yyyy_mm_dd(): string;
    }
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function (days: number): Date {
    if (!days) return this;
    console.log(this);
    let date = this;
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

    return date;
};

Date.prototype.isToday = function (): boolean {
    let today = new Date();
    return this.isSameDate(today);
};

Date.prototype.clone = function (): Date {
    return new Date(+this);
};

Date.prototype.isAnotherMonth = function (date: Date): boolean {
    return date && this.getMonth() !== date.getMonth();
};

Date.prototype.isWeekend = function (): boolean {
    return this.getDay() === 0 || this.getDay() === 6;
};

Date.prototype.isSameDate = function(date: Date): boolean {
    return date && this.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear() && this.getMonth() === date.getMonth() && this.getDate() === date.getDate();
};

Date.prototype.yyyy_mm_dd = function (): string {
    var mm = (this.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd = this.getDate().toString();

    return [this.getFullYear(), '-', mm.length === 2 ? '' : '0', mm, '-', dd.length === 2 ? '' : '0', dd].join(''); // padding
}
```

date.extensions.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
    if (!days)
        return this;
    console.log(this);
    var date = this;
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
};
Date.prototype.isToday = function () {
    var today = new Date();
    return this.isSameDate(today);
};
Date.prototype.clone = function () {
    return new Date(+this);
};
Date.prototype.isAnotherMonth = function (date) {
    return date && this.getMonth() !== date.getMonth();
};
Date.prototype.isWeekend = function () {
    return this.getDay() === 0 || this.getDay() === 6;
};
Date.prototype.isSameDate = function (date) {
    return date && this.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear() && this.getMonth() === date.getMonth() && this.getDate() === date.getDate();
};
Date.prototype.yyyy_mm_dd = function () {
    var mm = (this.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd = this.getDate().toString();
    return [this.getFullYear(), '-', mm.length === 2 ? '' : '0', mm, '-', dd.length === 2 ? '' : '0', dd].join(''); // padding
};
//# sourceMappingURL=date.extentions.js.map
```

Comment: What's in `apps/common/date.extentions.js`?

Comment: What if you add `'apps/common/date.extensions.js'` to packages and add `format: 'cjs'` to it?

Comment: added date.extensions files

Comment: Ah I see. Get rid of the `export {}` and it should work fine. I don't think SystemJS's format detection will pick that up since there are no assignments to `module.exports` and no `requires`. just import it as `import 'apps/common/date.extensions.js'`, without a `from` Also, remove the `declare global` wrapper since typechecking will fail when `export {}` is removed unless you do

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try your last suggestion. But wanted to let you know that adding format: cjs also solved it.

Comment: Right on. It works for the same reason. SystemJS performs module format detection which looks at the structure of the file and tries to determine the module format. If it detects CommonJS, it provides an `exports` object. setting `format` is a way to manually set the module format and if present, SystemJS will defer to the indicated format.

Comment: Thank you @AluanHaddad . I have no grasp on these. Thanks for helping me out. But what broke it? The date.extensions.ts had those lines since beginning. the tsconfig.json do say `"module": "commonjs"`

Comment: Yes, but SystemJS does not know that since you are not using the transpiler plugin. Probably worth setting `"format": "cjs"` for the entire `"apps"` package. But really, you should be using `"module": "system"` for best results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Either* remove the `export {}` from **apps/common/date.extensions.ts** *or* specify a module format of `"cjs"` explicitly.

SystemJS uses module format detection to determine which variables need to be provided in order for the module to be loaded. However, it will not recognize your `date.extensions.js` as CommonJS since there are no assignments to `module.exports` and no `require` calls (**1**).

To set the module format explicitly, add

```
packages: {
  "apps/common/date.extensions.js": {
    "format": "cjs"   
  },
  // ...
}
```

SystemJS will now use this metadata instead of a heuristic to determine the format and will therefore provide an `exports` object when it loads the module.

Alternately, since the file doesn't need to be a module, you can remove the `export {}` and the `declare global` wrapper.

1. Among other things, this involves regular expressions that attempt to detect CommonJS by searching for patterns such as `/exports\.*"\s*=\s*.+/g`. This isn't foolproof however, especially given that certain module formats that SystemJS detects are partial supersets of others. For example, an AMD module can match the same regular expression because it provides its own CommonJS compatibility layer. That said, SystemJS module format detection is powerful and allows many discordant module systems to interact automatically and correctly with no configuration required. Guy Bedford has done truly remarkable work.